# A Powershell script doesn't continue from where it supposedly stopped

Tags: excel, powershell

I created a Powershell script, to work semi-automatically on a (long) Excel-List (there are some little things the user still have to do on his or her own). I want it to save where it had stopped and then continue from there (the user has the ability to quit work after a block of the listed elements (he can decide the size of this blog)). Now my solution is that I save the variable that counts along in a separate file and then read it from there, jumping over the list elements it already worked on. However, this doesn't seem to work.

```
# Checking if the list was entered properly
# Checking where it has stopped
$counter=$args[0].replace(".csv", "c.ps1");
if(-not (Test-path $counter)){
        $num=1;
}else{
      $countn=$args[0].replace(".csv", "c.ps1");
       . ".\$countn";
}
...
$zzz=1;
$pause=$outNu; #outNu was entered by the user
$liste| ForEach-Object {
if($zzz -lt $num){
      $zzz++
      $zzz
      return;
 }
# work on the listelement
# with a litttle feedback from the use
$num++;
$pause--;
if(-not ($pause -eq 0)){
    "Elements in this block: "+$pause+"."
}else{
    $weg=Read-Host "Yo have finished one block, would you like to take a break? (If you say no you must do the next $outNu list elements.) Y/N";
    if($weg -eq "Y" -OR $weg -eq "y"){
           echo "`$num=$num;" > $counter;
           break;
    }
    $pause=$outNu;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's what I'd do if it were me. When they were done I'd have it save the Excel file first, and then get some detail to log about it to make sure there's no modifications between times that the script is run (oh yeah, what fun to open it in Excel and sort the records differently and then try and resume processing it with a script!). Personally I have the PowerShell Community Extensions installed on v3 so I have Get-Hash to get a MD5 HashString. If you have PSv4 there's a built in command to get the SHA Hash of a file. If you have neither, you could use the LastWriteTime property, and since I have to assume you have neither of the afore mentioned I'll use that in my example.

Now, this does load windows forms, and includes a function to create pop-up windows to interact with the user. If you don't like that you can revert the code back to your text prompts that you had and just use what you want I suppose.

```
#Load up the Windows Forms so we can display a message box as needed
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
#Function to display a message box with ease as needed
Function Show-MsgBox ($Title,$Text,$Button = "OK"){
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Text", "$Title", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::$Button, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
}
#Import the log file, or set one up if there isn't one. Make sure source file hasn't changed since we last updated it with the script.
$LogFile=$args[0].replace(".csv", ".log")
If((Test-Path $LogFile)){
    $Log = Import-Csv $LogFile
    If(!((GCI $Args[0]).LastWriteTime -eq ($Log|Select -Last 1).LastWriteTime)){If((Show-MsgBox -Title "File Change Confirmation" -Text "The Last Write Time of $($args[0]) is different than what is recorded in the log.`n`nWould you like to proceed with record number $CurrentRecord anyway?" -Button YesNo) -eq "No"){$null=Show-MsgBox -Title "Abort" -Text "Ending Script due to Last Write Time mismatch.`nPlease verify that the records in $(gci $args[0]|select Name) have not been modified before running this script again, or rename (or delete) the following before running this script again to start over:`n`n$LogFile";Break}
    $CurrentRecord = ($Log|Select -Last 1).EndRecord
    Write-Output "$($Args[0]) was last updated $($Log.LastWriteTime). Proceeding from record $CurrentRecord`." 
    } Else {
    $CurrentRecord=0
    Write-Output "No log file detected for $($Args[0]). Proceeding from record $CurrentRecord`." 
    }
}

$Loop = 1
#Loop for all remaining records, checking to see if the user wants to stop every $outNu records
For($i=$CurrentRecord;$i -le $Element.count;$i++){

    #Do Stuff to $Element[$i] with feedback from user

    $CurrentRecord++

    If($Loop -eq $outNu){
        If((Show-MsgBox -Title "Time for a break?" -Text "You have finished one block, would you like to take a break? (If you say no you must do the next $outNu list elements.))" -Button YesNo) -eq "Yes"){
            Break
        } else {
            $Loop = 1
        }
    } else {
        $Loop++
    }
}

#Save Excel file and exit Excel if desired

$LogFile = [pscustomobject]@{TimeStamp=$(Get-date -UFormat "%x %r");EndRecord=$CurrentRecord;LastWriteTime=$(GCI $args[0]|Select LastWriteTime)}
$LogFile|Export-Csv .\Desktop\RecordLog.log -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

And that's that. Looks for a log file (as CSV, but using the .log extension) for the specified Excel file. If it finds one it verified integrity of the source file against the log, and loops through all remaining records checking to see if they want to stop every $outNu records. Then it appends the log file, or creates it if there isn't one.

Comment: I don't knpw how work on the list itself. I need to be able to issue a coment foreach list element and give a speciall background color. I save the results to a html-file. This is much easier. But I take up your idea with the for-loop.